# Регулярное выражение на все символы

Tags: php

Есть регулярка

```
var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()-,.!&"«»';
```

Она проверяет следующее, я добавляю товар в корзину, если наименование проходит регулярку оно добавляется. Но вот например наименование товара `DESIRÉ Дуб натуральный золотистый` не добавляется из за апострофа. Как сделать регулярное выражение на все символы?

Comment: то есть вы на своём сайте валидируете свои же названия? :D

Comment: Открою секрет, но добавлять надо не названия, а идентификаторы товаров

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так я добавляют идетификатор. Но внутри я из базы получаю название товара и добавляю его в корзину. Так устроена библиотека codeigniter. Без названия не добавится

Comment: А зачем тут какая-то регулярка?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это внутренняя библиотека так прописана. Поэтому с ней и работаю. Добавляю id. Но библиотека просит добавлять параметры. if($res->num_rows()):
            $product= $res->row();
            $price = $product->price;
            $cart = array(
                'id'      => $this->input->post('id'),
                'qty'     => $quantity,
                'price'   => $price,
                'name'    => $product->title,
                'images'    => $img

            );
            $this->cart->insert($cart);

Comment: `\p{L}` вместо буквенных диапазонов

Answer (score 0):

А волшебный знак "\w" Matches any letter, digit or underscore", дополненный знаками препинания или нет не спасет?
Не говоря уже о том, что может выкинуть проверку, если она на все символы?
Ну или совсем по тупому ".*" в вашем случае скорее просто точка, без звезд.
"." Matches any character other than newline (or including line terminators with the /s flag)